# Indexpath Out of Range in My Array, Fatal Error in videoArray - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm getting and index path out of range error, but even when I check the code, I clearly having data in my array. Is it possible to safely unwrap it, or maybe somehow get over the error? I'm not sure exactly how.

I'm sure its an easy solution and I'm probably just overlooking it.

Error occurring inside of generatecellforthumbnail()

```
extension dashboard :UICollectionViewDataSource{

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if (collectionView == shopCollectionView){
    return myCategoryArray.count
   }
   
    return videoThumbnailArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = VideoCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell1", for: indexPath) as! videoCollectionCell
    
    
        cell.generateCellForThumbnail(model: videoThumbnailArray[indexPath.row])
    
    
    

    if (shopCollectionView == collectionView) {
        let cell2 = shopCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ShopCell1", for: indexPath) as! ShopCategoryCollectionViewCell
        
        cell2.generateCellforCategory(myCategoryArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell2
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to verify if **collectionView** in **cellForItem** method is a **shopCollectionView** before, like code below.

```
if (collectionView == shopCollectionView) {

  //do something

} else (collectionView == otherCollectionView) {

  //do something

} else {

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```